# Android kotlin : unable to read class file

Tags: android, file, class, kotlin

**EDIT : this was much simplier than I thought, I just needed to clean the project !**

I'm trying to define an interface inside a fragment containing a GridView to force any activity that would attach the fragment to implement that interface and the onImageSelected method.
For it once I check if the activity correctly implements the Interface, I cast it onto a callback object.

```
class MasterListFragment : Fragment(){

lateinit var mCallBack: OnImageClickListener

interface OnImageClickListener{
    fun onImageSelected(position: Int)
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if(context !is OnImageClickListener)
        throw ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement OnImageClickListener")
    else
        mCallBack = context
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val view = inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_master_list, container, false)
    var adapter = MasterListAdapter(context, AndroidImageAssets.getAll())
    var mGridView = view?.findViewById(R.id.master_grid_view) as GridView
    mGridView.adapter = adapter
    mGridView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ -> mCallBack.onImageSelected(position) }
    return view
}
```

And on my activity I just implement the interface and override the onImageSelected function.

But I run onto this error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Unable to read class file: '***\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug\com\example\android\myproject\MasterListFragment$mCallBack$1.class'

I tried without using a lateinit var and a simple var with no luck
What I don't get is that even after changing the variable name it still indicate the MasterListFragment$mCallBack$1.class

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by cleaning project, you can have a try